# Webpart showing all jobs stored in a SPS 2013 List

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, jobs

Created a Content Editor WebPart to show data from a SharePoint 2013 List relatd to Jobs.

WebParts works fine, but doesn't looks appealing and was looking for alternate options that would allow to showcase all jobs posted on a list to be visible on the main page or any other approach for Job based WebPart.

Comment: Can you provide the rough schema of your list?

Comment: Column 1: Poistion Title

Comment: Do you have only one column?

Comment: Show us a screenshot/drawing of the UI you want to create. Show us the code you have.. alas we are not telepathic

Comment: Pls check the screenshot for all columns information: 


http://imgur.com/lSZZm32

I have created a SPS list and set the expiration filter.

Comment: my jobs webpart is working, I`ve referenced a SPS list and the data is populating fine.

Need information on how can I delete an item from the list once the closing date associated with the item has reached.
We dont want the item to still be in the list after the closing date.